# Structure knockout.js application in different files

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0, knockout-3.2

I'm staring with Knockout.js and I didn't find much documentation about how to properly structure a knockout application.

It is easy to follow the [tutorial from the docs](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) and its multiple examples in them or in other pages, but there's no much about the good practices regarding the file structure.

I've seen [some videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1USsIW8aWE) of Steve Sanderson talking about how to architect a big project but they seem to be going a bit too far me. He mentions [the **Yeoman** tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yo) to generate a basic KO structure, but I'm using Node.js with Express.js and I already have another structure I'm working with and I'm not quite sure about how to mix both.

What I'm having at the moment is 3 main files:

- functions.js
- viewmodels.js (ko viewmodels and domain classes)
- events.js (for jQuery events)

As you can see, the `viewmodels.js` file will become bigger and bigger so I was thinking about separating each viewmodel with its associated domain classes in different files.

The problem I found is that some of my viewmodels are related with each other as they have to access to each other data at some point.

I'm making use of a mastermodel at the moment for it:

```
var MasterModel = function(){
    this.user = new UserViewModel();
    this.department = new DepartmentViewModel();
}

var mm = new MasterModel();
ko.applyBindings(mm);
```

So I can do things such as `mm.user.sayHi()` from a `departmentViewModel`

Any suggestions regarding the structure issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Yeoman tool generates a single-page-application structure, using CrossRoadsJS and RequireJS. Since you are using ExpressJS, I think the Yeoman structure does not fit well in your case.

If your view-models are getting bigger, inheritance is good choice.

Take a look at this [article](http://phrogz.net/JS/classes/OOPinJS.html), it is very good, and teaches how to make javascript inheritance, including private and public methods and properties. You can use it to create strong and reusable view-models.

About the good practices, this [blog](http://www.knockmeout.net/) is very good. It contains several articles about ko components and many others things.

Hope this help!